# basic input and the for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm just playing around with Python, very basic stuff.

The logic is as follows:

1. User provides 3 Celsius temperatures,
2. The body of the module count theirs Fahrenheit equivalents,
3. And prints them out as output.

I want to use the for loop for this task.

```
def main():
    c1, c2, c3 = input("Provide 3 Celsius temps. separated with a comma: ")
    for i in range(c1, c2, c3):
        fahrenheit = (9.0 / 5.0) * i + 32
        print "The temperature is", fahrenheit, "degrees Fahrenheit."

main()
```

Well, the above code only transtaltes and prints the first Fahrenheit tempatarute that user has provided.

Some hints needed please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `range()` call altogether:

```
for i in (c1, c2, c3):
```

Now you are making `(c1, c2, c3)` a tuple, and you can loop over that directly. `range()` is only needed when you need to make a series of integers.

When `print` is given an expression with a trailing comma, it won't print a newline, so to get all three values on one line, one (simple) way to do that would be:

```
c1, c2, c3 = input("Provide 3 Celsius temps. separated with a comma: ")
print "The temperatures are", 
for i in range(c1, c2, c3):
    fahrenheit = (9.0 / 5.0) * i + 32
    print fahrenheit,
print "degrees Fahrenheit."
```

We can make this complicated fast, work through your tutorials a bit more and more powerful Python structures will be available soon enough. :-)

Comment: btw. is it possible for the output to be all 3 Fahrenheit temps printed in one line each after a comma?  I mean not to change too much of the code there?  like this: The temperatures are: F1, F2, F3 respectively

Comment: Everything is possible; it'd be easier if you worked your way through the tutorials some more though. I am not sure you are ready for things like list comprehensions yet, for example.

Comment: thanks, actually i'm going though Zelle's book: Python Programming and wanted to kinda speed it up but you probably right ;) thx again